# zsh: ignore symbolic links in completion list returned by _files

Tags: zsh, symlink, autocomplete

I am new to writing zsh completions. How can I ignore symbolic links from showing in completion returned by `_files -W /path/to/folder/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A test directory is populated:

```
% cd && mkdir foo && cd foo
% touch file1 file2
% mkdir dir1
% ln -s file1 link1
% ln -s dir1 link2
```

and with the not-symlink glob qualifiers `^` `@` the symlinks may
be ignored.

```
% print *
dir1 file1 file2 link1 link2
% print *(^@)
dir1 file1 file2
```

A completion then can use the `-g` flag to `_path_files` which `_files`
uses, many ZSH completion functions and builtins have to be chased down
such indirections:

> -g pattern
> Specifies  that only files matching the pattern should be
> completed.

So perhaps:

```
#compdef foo
_arguments "1:file:_files -W ~/foo -g '*(^@)'" && return 0
```

However, this completes on symlinks that point to directories:

```
% foo <<MASHTABKEY>>
dir1/   file1   file2   link2@

% ln -s /etc/passwd
% ln -s /etc
% foo <<MASHTABKEY>>
dir1/   etc@    file1   file2   link2@
```

If symlinks that point to directories are a problem, a different line of
attack is to complete on all files in the `~/foo` directory

```
#compdef foo
_arguments '1:file:_files -W ~/foo' && return 0
```

and to then specify an `all-files` completion style for `foo`:

```
% zstyle ':completion:*:*:foo:*:*' file-patterns '*(^@):all-files'
% foo <<MASHTABKEY>>
dir/ file1 file2
```

Comment: I did some testing, and your second method is more accurate... It works even if the directory only has symbolic links, and no regular files. In that case the first method still shows symbolic links in completion, which is undesirable. Second method with ``zstyle ':completion:*:*:foo:*:*' file-patterns '*(^@):all-files'`` works under all cases.

Comment: I just asked a corollary/follow up question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/717679/456507