# zsh glob qualifier with negated null glob works like it should with null glob

Tags: zsh, wildcards, autocomplete

Note: Please don't respond about this being a XY situation. I am trying to understand how a globbing pattern works, not trying to achieve a specific result. Am also not interested in other ways to achieve this with zstyle, etc.

Recently I was in a situation where I wanted to [complete only symbolic links from a specific directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716574) as a function's argument. A pattern like `*(@)` works as an argument to `-g` of `_files` as long as the directory has at least one symbolic link. If there are no symbolic links in the directory, the completion filter fails as it now completes regular files (non symbolic links)... So I went through the documentation, and it seemed adding `N` (NULL GLOB) qualifier is the answer. I changed the pattern to `*(@N)`, but that still returns regular files when there are no symbolic links. Surprisingly, adding a negation in front of N (pattern `*(@^N)`) makes it work correctly under all cases. But am a little unsure if this is because I hit a zsh bug (and this pattern will stop working in future) or if this pattern really makes sense and is worth relying on.

It would be great if someone would be able to confirm that the pattern below works not because its a zsh bug, and what it means. Here's a test file `foocomp.zsh`:

```
function foo {
    echo "foo called with $1"
}

function _foo {
    _files -g '*(@^N)' -W $PWD/foodir/
}

function bar {
    echo "bar called with $1"
}

function _bar {
    _files -g '*(@N)' -W $PWD/foodir/
}

compdef _foo foo

compdef _bar bar
```

Steps:

1. Save `foocomp.zsh` file to some directory
2. mkdir foodir && cd foodir
3. touch hello && ln -s hello world && cd ..
4. source `foocomp.zsh`
5. Type foo or bar and press tab, it should only complete world.
6. Delete symbolic link world
7. Type foo and press tab again, it would not complete anything (which is desired behavior)
8. Type bar and press tab again, it will complete hello.

Answer (score 1):

The `_files` function is a wrapper around `_path_files` and the
`_path_files` code involves not just a glob but various other logic and
zstyle settings; adding a `-g glob` influences what the `pats` array
contains, sets a `gopts` flag that hits up various branches, and there
is additional code that inspects whether elements in `pats` contain a
glob qualifier, or not. You would really need to trace this function
call to see what is going on for varied arguments, and how glob
qualifiers influence the following code.

```
% less ${^fpath}/_path_files(N)
```

A global zstyle may interfere with the `_path_files` code in unexpected
and hard to debug ways. For example you could set the `*(@^N)` glob for
the `foo` command, and then some months later you or some random plugin
makes a conflicting zstyle change, and then some months later you notice
that the `*(@^N)` no longer operates as expected and have no clue why.
With tracing we can see what is going on and test whether my informal
reasoning is true:

```
% functions -t _path_files
```

Actually that's pretty annoying; `_complete_debug` will instead put the
completion trace into a temporary file for you
(<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd>):

```
% bindkey | grep _debug
"^X?" _complete_debug
```

So we have four cases, `foo` and `bar` with and without a link present
in `foodir`. So after some key pressing...

```
% mv zsh3827foo2 withlink-foo
% mv zsh3827bar3 withlink-bar
% mv zsh3827foo4 nolink-foo
% mv zsh3827bar5 nolink-bar
```

These might actually be easier to tell apart if the completion is
modified between `_complete_debug` calls so that the command name
differences do not complicate matters. Anyways, a notable difference,
eventually, is

```
-       +_path_files:468> compfiles -p tmp1 accex '' ' ' .. fake '*(#q@^N)'
-       +_path_files:472> tmp1=
+       +_path_files:468> compfiles -p tmp1 accex '' ' ' .. fake '*(#q@N)'
+       +_path_files:472> tmp1=( )
```

that `^` for the correct `foo` sets `tmp1=` while the incorrect `bar`
sets an empty array `tmp1=( )`, and then takes a long branch elsewhere
before rejoining the shared completion track. So this is a fairly subtle
point, and the usual error message is swallowed somewhere within
`compfiles`; on the command line it can be seen that `^@` merely turns
off `NULL_GLOB` in a directory with no symlinks present:

```
% a=( *(#q@^N) )
zsh: no matches found: *(#q@^N)
% a=( *(#q@N) )
```

Over in `Src/Zle/computil.c` the `compfiles` function is documented to
return an array for `parnam1`:

```
 * SYNOPSIS:
 *     1. compfiles -p  parnam1 parnam2 skipped matcher sdirs parnam3 varargs [.
.varargs]
...
 *     1. Set parnam1 to an array of patterns....
 *        ${(P)parnam1} is an in/out parameter.
```

So I guess this might be a bug if `compfiles` is always supposed to
return an array? But that's probably something that should be hashed out
with the ZSH developers. Otherwise for this case I would still use the
zstyle solution to avoid global zstyle changes from potentially
affecting this completion code.